# directive callback function not firing from inside $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an angular directive that recieves a callback function as an attribute.

```
<my-dir ng-model="foo.bar" on-change="func(data)"></my-dir>
```

In the definition of the directive I assign this attribute as follows

```
scope: {onChange: '&onChange'}
```

Now, in my link function, if I call **scope.onChange({data: 23});** everything works fine. But if I make this same call inside a $watch function it fails.

```
scope.$watch("stepId", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    scope.onChange({data: 23}); //why it does NOT work ????
})
```

Comment: This is strange. Can you add more context?

Comment: @katmanco no error, the function is simply not called.

Comment: @dfsq sure, what more info do you need :)

Comment: Do you watch it in link function?

Comment: is the actual watch listener called?

Comment: Post directive code.

Comment: While starting to work on a fiddle, i realized that i was using the directive twice and in one I simply did not set the on-change attribute. So thanks for you mental support :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of watching "stepId", you should watch a function returned value.

```
    scope.$watch( function(){ return scope.stepId; }, function( newValue, oldValue){
        if( typeof newValue == 'undefined' )
            return;

        scope.onChange( {data: scope.stepId});
    });
```

You should better make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the stepId in the scope of the app or directive ,otherwise $watch will not listen your variable